# Application built by Qt for WinRT running slower than Qt for Android on same Windows 8.1 host

Tags: qt, windows-runtime, qt5, qtgui, qt5.4

I'm using Qt 5.4.1 (for WinRT and Android) on same windows 8.1 host and project using GUI (such as QListView). I see the application running on Windows runtime (built by Qt creator for both WinRT and Android) very different in terms of performance (WinRT build is slower than the Android one about 2-3 times).

How can I solve this? Thanks!

P.S.: I'm trying to use QListView (deploying to windows phone 8.1) and QScroller but is not as fast as listview in Windows phone (Maybe something's not optimized because app running in windows 8.1 (target = host) is slow too).

Comment: What do you mean by performance? Startup time? Time it takes to complete certain operations? Is it also reproducible when run on Win 8.1 itself (target=host)? I'd try with a profiler.

Comment: yes, time it take one operation (see clearly when fill rect with transparent with background of widget), I have measured time by QTime in paintEvent. Yes, the app is run on windows 8.1 (target = host). I'm thinking about that rebuild Qt using vs2013 with optimize flags !?. One thing I found out that use QPixmap in paintEvent event slow than without??

Comment: You probably do too much in paintEvent. Show the code that you have in paintEvent.